# How to implement a Web Service in C#

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

I want to implement a Web Service in C#. Basically, expose some methods to my clients through a Web Service

**Is there an easy example of how can I do this?** 
 
**How should I declare the methods, classes, etc?**

Comment: I'm with Oded. - I despair seeing this sort of question when a simple google search would have brought you all you needed.  Seems stack overflow is getting more and more of this type of question when it really is easier to google (which in itself will bring back a massive number of stack overflow refs) - for a self moderating community, we seem to be lacking self moderation :(

Comment: Questions like this are already discussed on meta. Hopefully we will have new close reason soon: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86043/introduce-a-general-reference-close-reason SO is for asking questions about problem you have not for asking questions where simple query in google give you results: http://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=.NET+web+services+tutorial

Answer (score 3):

You want to look at Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) web services. This is the latest implementation of services on the .NET stack.

Eric White has a great "File > New..." blog on getting started.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2010/05/11/getting-started-building-a-wcf-web-service.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Here there are some examples:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webservices/myservice.aspx

http://www.15seconds.com/issue/010430.htm

http://blogs.sitepoint.com/net-web-services-5-steps/